# Trying to run Full Eth node geth or any other client on Raspberry Pi 4B with 2 TB SSD

Tags: cpp-ethereum, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to gather some information on whether anyone is still running the nodes on RPi (Raspberry Pi), since all the guides and tutorials i could find are all pre 2023.

Also, i see that many of the requirements of running Eth nodes especially on a size and performance constrained device like RPi are constantly changing ( need more ram,storage etc.).

Any advice please? Thanks!